# var not defined - backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I am quite new to backbone.js i am trying to access a var from file B to file A. currently i have declared file A as below

```html
window.dog = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model : animal,

    initialize : function(){
        _.bindAll(this);
    },
  // this is where i am getting an error saying i have not defined dog
  var dog=  new dog();
})
```

File B :

```html
var  dog = function () {
    this.eats = {};
    this.dance.REQUEST = {};
    this.walk.REQUEST.LIST = [];

};
```

Now I want the method eat to be called from script A how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is a syntax error. you can't just define a variable inside an object.

```html
window.dog = Backbone.Collection.extend({
 model : animal,
 initialize : function(){
  _.bindAll(this);
 },
    // change to this 
    dog :  new dog()
});
```

Comment: even after changing it to dog: new dog() , still i  am not able to access eats from file B

Comment: Thing that you are asking is out of scope of this question. Ask it is as separate question. @DivakarLuffy

Answer (score 0):

As Satish already suggested, setting `dog` property to the extend object will solve the issue. Also make sure `dog` is available in FILE A from FILE B. You could try the following:

```js
var animal = {};
var dog = function() {
  this.eats = {
    food: 'chicken'
  };
  this.dance = {
    REQUEST: {}
  };
  this.walk = {
    REQUEST: {
      LIST: []
    }
  };
};
window.dogCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: animal,
  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this);
  },
  dog: new dog()
});
console.log(new window.dogCollection().dog.eats);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.4.0/backbone-min.js"></script>
```